# How to use Symfony's default autoloading in an external file

Tags: php, symfony, autoload

For debugging and testing purposes, I have created an "external" php file in the top directory of my Symfony project, and I call it with php from the command line. So far I did not succeed
in using Symfony's default autoloading in that external file. I tried each of the following in turn the beginning of the file :

```
require 'app/autoload.php'; 

require 'vendor/autoload.php'

require 'composer/autoload_real.php'
```

But none of them work : every time I try something like

```
$check=class_exists(AppBundle/Entity/User);
```

my debugger tells that $check is set to false so that my User class is not recognized by php. What is the correct way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first require is sufficient (that's the Symfony autoloader) it loads the other two files itself.

class_exists returns false because the class isn't autoloaded yet therefore the function returns false.

```
require 'app/autoload.php'; // This autoloader loads also your vendors and composer
$user = new AppBundle/Entity/User(); // now the autoloader is called!
$check=class_exists(AppBundle/Entity/User); // the class is autoloaded so true!
```